# How to CAC enable the APEX 5 Application

Tags: oracle-apex, cac

Looking for Step by Step Instructions on how to CAC enable the APEX 5 Application.
I have read the related Oracle documentation, but would appreciate if somebody who has gone through this exercise would provide the step by step instructions.
Thanks

Comment: CAC is quite an ambiguous term, can you provide context?

Comment: Sure - the DoD Common Access Card (CAC) used for online identification to access US government systems.

Comment: Ahh, there are a few examples out there showing how to interact with barcodes. I would imagine you would scan, ask for their associated pin, and you're authenticated? You could use the custom authentication example.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is still looking for the answer to this, I wrote a paper and a series of blog posts with the solution:

- https://pmdba.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/apex-authentication-with-a-smart-card-part-1-web-server/
- https://pmdba.wordpress.com/2019/12/20/apex-authentication-with-a-smart-card-part-2-workspace/
- https://pmdba.wordpress.com/2019/12/30/apex-authentication-with-a-smart-card-part-3-application/
- https://pmdba.files.wordpress.com/2019/09/ha-oracle-ords-apex-with-http-header-authentication.pdf